Einstein Relation; Equilibrium State of a Diffusive system
Consider the convection-diffusion equation with no sources/sinks:
$$\frac{\partial c}{\partial t}  = \mathbf{\nabla} \cdot (D \mathbf{\nabla} c - \mathbf{v} c)$$
Where $c$ is the concentration of the variable of interest, D is the diffusion coefficient, and $\mathbf{v}$ is the bulk velocity. Consider the case where $\mathbf{v} = \xi^{-1} \mathbf{F},$ and $\mathbf{F} = -\nabla U$ for some potential energy $U.$ If $D$ and $\xi$ are constant, then a solution to the time equilibrium equation:
$$\frac{\partial c}{\partial t}  = 0=\mathbf{\nabla} \cdot (D \mathbf{\nabla} c + \xi^{-1}c \nabla U )$$
can be found by considering
$$D \mathbf{\nabla} c + \xi^{-1}c \nabla U =0.$$
This has solution $c \propto \exp{-\frac{U}{D\xi}}.$ On the consideration that we expect this to agree with the Boltzmann distribution, we have derived the Einstein relation:
$$D\xi = k_B T.$$

Question: Under specified boundary conditions we should expect a
unique equillibrium solution. Which boundary conditions will lead to
the above solution being the physically correct solution?

Now consider a simpler case in one dimension. Suppose now that the diffusion coefficient is not constant, but that there is no convection:
$$0=\frac{\partial}{\partial x} \left( D(x) \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x}\right)$$
$$A=D(x) \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x}$$
$$\phi_{\text{eq}} = \int \frac{A}{D(x)}dx +B$$

Question: In this case, would we also expect this to agree with a
Boltzmann distribution $e^{-\frac{\mu(x)}{k_B T}}$? This would imply
$$\mu(x) \propto -k_B T \ln{\left(\int \frac{A}{D(x)}dx +B \right)}$$

That may look strange, but on the other hand a spatially varying diffusion coefficient should create a spatially varying density, and so it should have some contribution to the chemical potential.

I think your line of reasoning is correct, I should check better for what concerns the solutions and the second question. However, If I do not find time to do so, I recommend consulting the bible of diffusion equations, namely: "The Mathematics of Diffusion" by Crank
